# Calculate the pixel distance to three defined pixel in matlab

Tags: matlab, distance

I want to classify pixels of one tiff image according to pixel's RGB colour. The input is an image and three predefined colours for water(r0,g0,b0), forest(r1,g1,b1) and building(r2,g2,c2). The classification is based on the distance between image pixel and these three colors. If a pixel is closet to the water, the pixel is water and changed it the water RGB. The distance is calculated as (one sample) sqrt((x-r0)^2+(y-g0)^2+(z0-b0)^2)

The sample implementation is:

```
a=imread(..);
[row col dim] = size(a);   % dim =3 
for i=1:row
   for j=1:col
       dis1=sqrtCal(a(i,j,:)-water) 
       dis2=sqrtCal(a(i,j,:)-forest) 
       dis3=sqrtCal(a(i,j,:)-build)
       a(i,j,:) = water;
       if  dis2< dis1
           dis1 = dis2
           a(i,j,:) = forest
       end
       dis3=sqrt(a(i,j,:)-build)
       if dis3<dis1
          a(i,j,:) = build
       end
   end
end
```

This implementation should work. The problem is that the two for loops is not a good choice.

So is there any good alternatives in the Matlab? The 
             `D = pdist(X,distance)`
Seems not appliable for my case.

Comment: So the result would be a MxN array containing 1, 2, 3 values, where M, N are the image size? And, is the number of references colors fixed (3 in your case)?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed. The image is M*N*3, in which the '3' is (R,G,B)

Comment: In the meantime I've written an answer for an arbitrary number of reference colors

Comment: Instead of manually converting from `uint8` to `double`, you could use `im2double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want. The number of reference colors is arbitrary (`3` in your example). Each reference color is defined as a row of the matrix `ref_colors`. Let `M`x`N` denote the number of pixels in the original image. Thus the original image is an `M`x`N`x`3` array.

`result_index` is an `M`x`N` array which for each original pixel contains the index of the closest reference color.

`result` is a `M`x`N`x`3` array in which each pixel has been assigned the RBG values of the closest reference color.

```
im = rand(10,12,3);          %// example image
ref_colors = [ .1 .1 .8; ... %// water
               .3 .9 .2; ... %// forest
               .6 .6 .6 ];   %// build: example reference colors
dist = sum(bsxfun(@minus, im, permute(ref_colors, [3 4 2 1])).^2, 3);
    %// 4D array containing the distance from each pixel to each reference color.
    %// Dimensions are: 1st: pixel row, 2nd: pixel col, 3rd: not used,
    %// 4th: index of reference color
[~, result_index] = min(dist, [], 4); %// compute arg min along 4th dimension
result = reshape(ref_colors(result_index,:), size(im,1), size(im,2), 3);
```

Comment: You can probably avoid `squeeze` with `min(..[],4)`?

Comment: It seems ``result`` is the minimal distance along the 3rd dimesion. But how to update the original matrix `im`.  For example, im(2,3,:) is classified as water, how assign im(2,3,:) with water RGB, which is (.1, .1, .8) here?

Comment: @shijiexu `result` already contains the updated color values, as you specify in your answer. Check my example

Comment: Thanks all. This code seems OK for me and i make its mean clear now. A minor issue is that the generated image is not as i expected (I update my post). Maybe this is because the script is executed on a machine which the image writting library is out of date.

Comment: @shijiexu Perhaps `imwrite` for `tiff` expects 0...1 values, not 0...255 values. Try `imwrite(double(result)/255, "new.tif")`

Comment: @LuisMendo, you are right. The last time i use matlable is 12 years, and some new syntax seems strange to me now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @shijiexu Glad it worked. Maybe edit your question then, by changing or removing the last part, so as not to confuse future readers

Answer (score 1):

This one is another [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based solution, but stays in `3D` and could be more efficient -

```
%// Concatenate water, forest, build as a 2D array for easy processing
wfb = cat(2,water(:),forest(:),build(:))

%// Calculate square root of squared distances & indices corresponding to min vals
[~,idx] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus,reshape(a,[],3),permute(wfb,[3 1 2])).^2,2),[],3)

%// Get the output with the minimum from the set of water, forest & build
a_out = reshape(wfb(:,idx).',size(a))
```

Comment: Good idea: one less dimension. To achieve that you need to collapse the first two dimensions of the original image into one, but it's probably more efficient

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah I find `reshape` to be less expensive at times!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the statistics toolbox installed, you can use this version based on `knnsearch`, that scales well for a large number of colors.

```
result_index = knnsearch(ref_colors, reshape(im,[],3));
result = reshape(ref_colors(result_index,:), size(im));
```